# LINQ - to Entities does not recognise the method Boolean (int32)

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, int32

I have a class called Person that has a method called hasPermission(Int 32)

I'm trying to call some linq and have tried various options but haven't managed to find a solution yet if anyone has any ideas, please can you help.

I currently have

```
IEnumerable<Person> co = this.Person();

//this.Person().Where(o => o.IsDeleted == false);

//    src.Where(o => o.IsDeleted == false).Select(v => new { Text = v.Name });
return this.Json(co,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

you can see a couple of the other things i have tried in the comments.

Thanks for your help in advance

Gemma

Comment: So, `Person` is a method that returns an `IEnumerable<Person>`? According to its name, it probably isn't. The `Person` method's signature would be helpful.

Comment: What is the role of `hasPermission` here? You're looking for a solution, but don't clearly state the problem.

Comment: yes the person is IEnumerable.  The person class has a method for hasPermission(int permissionID) which is used to set the permissions of the person.  However all I want to do is return a list of names from person.  The problem is being caused by the LINQ to Entities method

Comment: error as below:

context.Exception = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean HasPermission(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: I figured that, but why didn't you post that to begin with? (like `this.Person().Where(p => p.HasPermission(2))`. Anyway, as long as you're operating on IQueryable everything must be translatable to SQL. That does not work with a common instance method.

Answer (score 1):

OK, as this is LINQ to Entities, you need to use `AsEnumerable` method:

```
// this.Person().Where(o => !o.IsDeleted) is translated by EF, the rest isn't
this.Person().Where(o => !o.IsDeleted).AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.hasPermission(5));
```

The `AsEnumerable` extension method wraps your LINQ to Entities result into a generic `IEnumerable`. Thus, subsequent LINQ isn't translated to SQL by EF, but just executed.

See MSDN for further information on `AsEnumerable` too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx